# data uri in track tag for video not decoded correctly by chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, video.js

I have a simple video tag in my page using videojs :

```
<video id="videoPlayer" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;"  class="video-js"   controls preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%"
data-setup="{}">
<source id="videoSource" src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type='video/mp4'>


<p class="vjs-no-js">
  To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
  <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
</p>
</video>
```

now when I add a `<track>` tag with a file or a data base64 encoded uri everything still works fine and the subtitles are showing but once the .vtt base64 encoded file for the track contains special characters the browser just displays strange characters. This only happens when the file is added as a base64 encoded uri for example :

```
<track kind="captions" src="testSubs.srt"/>
```

works just fine but if I do something like :

```
<track kind="captions" src="data:text/vtt;base64,MYBASE64ENCODEDBYTES... "/>
```

the shown captions are then all garbled, this only happens on chrome, tested on firefox and the uri encoded file gets decoded correctly. How can I fix this for chrome ? I dont see whee the issue is, the data is utf8 and works fine on other browsers.

Sorry for my bad english, not native language, thanks to all.

Comment: Just a suggestion for debugging this issue:  If it's straight-forward to do, I'd suggest that you temporarily remove all the videojs-specific coding (so you're then using Chrome's native player), and debug that to see if the same symptoms remain.  If that solves it, then put back the videojs-specific coding.